# jQuery .clone() of audio tag with new ID not playing on IE or FF from inside a .click()

Tags: jquery

jQuery .clone() of audio tag with new ID not playing on IE or FF from inside a .click()

I have a very simple audio tag in the body of my page

```
<audio preload="auto" id="badclick">
<source src="audio/button-4.ogg"/>
<source src="audio/button-4.mp3"/>
<source src="audio/button-4.wav"/>
<source src="audio/button-4.m4a"/>
</audio>
```

I use some code to clone it and assign an ID 'badclick_1_1'

```
var gclk = 'badclick_1_1';
sounds[1] = $('#badclick');  
$(sounds[1]).clone(true).attr('id', gclk).insertAfter(sounds[1]);
```

I try and play the sound from inside a .click() handler but although it plays in Chrome it doesn't on IE and FF

```
var vol = .05;
var xclk = 'badclick_1_1';
var audiobad = $('#' + xclk)[0];
audiobad.volume=vol;
audiobad.play();
```

Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: A quick test for me in FF has no problems. Any exceptions? Can you provide a fiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: On one computer IE doesn't work on another it does. Hmmm... I'll put together something for fiddle and see what happens there.

Comment: This works on Chrome and IE but not F...   http://jsfiddle.net/dolomite13/uRZFU/11/